# always false conditional statement - sonarqube

Tags: c#, sonarqube, conditional-statements

while analyzing my code in sonarqube i'm getting an error saying the conditional always evaluates to false and subsequent code is never executed in the below code:

```
private RedirectItem FindItemToItemRedirect(string url)
{
    var redirectDefinition = RedirectDefinition?.ItemsRedirects;
    if (!redirectDefinition?.Any() ?? false)
        return null;

    RedirectItem result;
    if (redirectDefinition.TryGetValue(url, out result))
        return result;

    return null;
}
```

its saying the `if (!redirectDefinition?.Any() ?? false)` is always false and the null beneath it is never executed. however in my IDE/with resharper i am getting no errors for this in the code. is this a false positive in sonarqube and i should just suppress it?

thanks

Comment: it is a known bug

Comment: That line could certainly be rewritten to be more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in sonarqube described in here: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-dotnet/issues/2369

Instead of suppressing it, you can write:

```
if (!redirectDefinition?.Any().GetValueOrDefault())
```